# Word count in descending order using java lambdas

Tags: java, java-8, word-count

I have a string on which I want to do word count in descending order. I have the code as below:

```
String[] line = "some text some spaces".split(" ");
Map<String, Long> map1 = Arrays.stream(line).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
Map<String, Long> map2 = map1.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed()).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (v1, v2) -> v2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Above gives me a word count in descending order of number of times a word appears. Is it possible to do this operation just once, I mean to merge line 2 and 3 into one. This would then require me to create just one stream.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this without two streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way (it does create two streams and does merge the two lines of code):

```
Map<String, Long> map = Arrays.stream("some text some spaces".split(" "))
                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                              .entrySet()
                              .stream()
                              .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(),
                                        (v1, v2) -> v2, LinkedHashMap::new));

System.out.println(map); // This prints: {some=2, spaces=1, text=1}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that it's possible. Since Collect is a terminal operation and you can't reuse the stream after calling a terminal operation.

here is some information from the below article:

> Stream operations are either intermediate or terminal. Intermediate operations return a stream so we can chain multiple intermediate operations without using semicolons. Terminal operations are either void or return a non-stream result.
>
> Java 8 streams cannot be reused. As soon as you call any terminal operation the stream is closed.

You can read this [article](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) for more details.

Comment: Although I accept the answer from Prasad, which essentially does nothing different than what I have done but its still is not a perfect solution!

Comment: I am ok with not doing a "collect" operation too early but would still only like to just have one stream operation. I hope someone can answer this.